can't order y-axis plotly express timeline with scatter plot on secondary y-axis
I have a plotly express timeline, and I'm adding a scatter plot on the secondary y-axis, on top of the timeline bars. Because of the secondary_y, I have to use make_subplots, then add the traces from the Timeline figure to the main figure.  This is working fine, except the category_orders breaks. If I plot fig_timeline directly, the category_orders work. But after placing the traces into the main figure, the categories appear in some random order. Any ideas how I can work around this?
fig = make_subplots(shared_xaxes=True, specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig_timeline = px.timeline(df, 
    x_start='x_start', 
    x_end='x_end', 
    y='vm_type', 
    color='bartype',
    category_orders={'vm_type':['a','b','c','d']},
    hover_name='bartype',
    )

for d in fig_timeline.data:
    fig.add_trace(d)


You need to apply the fig_timeline layout to the main figure as well, ie. fig.update_layout(fig_timeline.layout). Though you may also need to merge other layout props for the scatter trace, in which case we would need more details (mwe with sample data and the code that add the scatter trace).

THANK YOU!!! Updating the layout did the trick. Yay.
